# Pandas append dataframe to another not merging column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes A & B, both of them have numeric column names. Following is the structure of dataframe A

```
| 1001  | 1002  | 1003  | 1004  |
----------------------------------
| value | value | value | value |
| value | value | value | value |
| value | value | value | value |
```

Structure of dataframe B

```
| 9999  | 1003  |
----------------
| value | value_x |
```

I'm trying to get this type of dataframe

```
| 1001  | 1002  | 1003    | 1004  |  9999  |
----------------------------------
| value | value | value   | value |  nan   |
| value | value | value   | value |  nan   |
| value | value | value   | value |  nan   |
| nan   | nan   | value_x | nan   |  value |
```

I'm trying this piece of code, but it's not working. It instead duplicates the column `1003` instead of merging the values

```
X=A.append(B)
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Try using pd.merge

Comment: @SreeramTP dataframe is created dynamically, won't know what columns to be merged on

Comment: It [defaults to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) when not merging on indexes.

Comment: Tested and if both columns names are numeric, it working nice.

Comment: I get the error `no common columns to merge on` but the duplicated columns has the exact same text

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri - Maybe some whitesapces? What is `print (A.columns.tolist())` and `print (B.columns.tolist())`  with real data?

Comment: @jezrael columns in dataframe A are printing has `string` in the list, while it seems to be just numbers in dataframe B. How can I change the `dtype` of columns?

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri - Check my answer. Btw, `pd.concat([A, B], ignore_index=True)` is alternative to `X = A.append(B, ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need same types of columns e.g. `str`:

```
B.columns = B.columns.astype(str)
```

Or `int`:

```
A.columns = A.columns.astype(int)
```

Then your solution working nice, only added `ignore_index=True` for avoid duplicated index:

```
X = A.append(B, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

you're looking for dataframe concatenation:

```
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,3)), columns=[0,1,2])

A
Out: 
          0         1         2
0  0.406870  0.590722  0.426807
1  0.963046  0.699453  0.935914
2  0.850077  0.251939  0.140186
3  0.278246  0.302475  0.451266
4  0.643660  0.792514  0.875318

B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,2)), columns=[2, 3])

B
Out: 
          2         3
0  0.921935  0.981288
1  0.384787  0.921707
2  0.667739  0.488965
3  0.329663  0.779093
4  0.320227  0.744742

pd.concat([A, B], ignore_index=True)
Out: 
          0         1         2         3
0  0.406870  0.590722  0.426807       NaN
1  0.963046  0.699453  0.935914       NaN
2  0.850077  0.251939  0.140186       NaN
3  0.278246  0.302475  0.451266       NaN
4  0.643660  0.792514  0.875318       NaN
5       NaN       NaN  0.921935  0.981288
6       NaN       NaN  0.384787  0.921707
7       NaN       NaN  0.667739  0.488965
8       NaN       NaN  0.329663  0.779093
9       NaN       NaN  0.320227  0.744742
```